# Split a text file into muliple files

Tags: batch-file, text-processing, filesplitting

My sample text file is the following:

```
1.  -77.41936   37.238461
2.  -77.41932   37.238466
3.  -77.419275  37.238454
4.  -77.419247  37.23843
5.  -77.419235  37.2384
6.  -77.419243  37.238363
7.  -77.419268  37.238337
8.  -77.419292  37.238326
9.  #N/A    #N/A
10. #N/A    #N/A
11. #N/A    #N/A
12. #N/A    #N/A
13. #N/A    #N/A
14. #N/A    #N/A
15. #N/A    #N/A
16. #N/A    #N/A
17. -77.417944  37.23563
18. -77.417906  37.235634
19. -77.417869  37.235624
20. -77.417845  37.235605
21. -77.417829  37.235583
22. -77.417826  37.235552
23. -77.417841  37.235521
24. -77.417858  37.235506
25. -77.417877  37.235496
26. #N/A    #N/A
27. #N/A    #N/A
28. #N/A    #N/A
29. #N/A    #N/A
30. #N/A    #N/A
31. #N/A    #N/A
32. #N/A    #N/A
33. #N/A    #N/A
34. -77.433782  37.23745
35. -77.433175  37.237797
36. -77.433107  37.237815
37. -77.433047  37.237814
38. -77.432991  37.2378
39. -77.432933  37.237766
40. -77.432681  37.237481
41. -77.432648  37.237432
42. -77.432634  37.237378
43. -77.432638  37.237323
44. -77.432687  37.237209
45. -77.432714  37.23716
46. -77.432772  37.237083
47. -77.432844  37.237015
48. -77.432993  37.23694
49. #N/A    #N/A
50. #N/A    #N/A
51. #N/A    #N/A
52. #N/A    #N/A
53. #N/A    #N/A
>>54.   #N/A    #N/A
```

I want to separate each block of numbers. These blocks are separated by random number of lines containing `#N/A` `#N/A`. Each block must be save into different text file named `segment"blocknumber".txt`.

Is there an easy way to do this through batch file?

Comment: Are the line numbers part of the textfile and do you want to keep them (unchanged) to the new files?

Comment: Sorry, they don't exist on the text file. I just put them to organize the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=1
set flag=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in (t.t) do (
  if "%%i" neq "#N/A #N/A" ( 
    set flag=0
    echo %%i>>file!count!.txt
  ) else (
    if !flag!==0 set /a count+=1 
    set flag=1
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. In the text file called "t.t" I could split into different files. The only issue I had was that it was "tab" between the #N/A in the file instead of space. My file content must have lost the formatting when I pasted it here. You saved me a lot of time.